# Анимация изображения или текста в окне приложения

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlabel, qpropertyanimation, qgraphicsopacityeffect

Проще говоря мне нужно чтобы на экран медленно выводилось изображение или текст, если это возможно в *PyQt5*. 
Помогите кто может.

Мой код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class Button(QPushButton):
    mouseMoved = pyqtSignal()
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.mouseMoved.emit()

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("img.png")
        self.lbl.setPixmap(self.pix)
        self.lbl.resize(250, 350)
        self.lbl.move(470, 1000)
        self.lbl.close()
        self.btn = QPushButton(self)
        self.btn.setMouseTracking(True);
        self.btn.setText("Кнопка")
        self.btn.setStyleSheet("background: pink; color: Black; border-radius: 34px;}")
        self.btn.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Pusia-Bold.otf", 17, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
        self.btn.resize(300, 150)
        self.btn.move(430, 1550)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.image)
        self.show()
    def image(self):
        self.lbl.show()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = MainWindow()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Все возможно. Покажите, пожалуйста, код, который вы уже написали.

Comment: Изменил вопрос, поставил там код

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Класс `QGraphicsOpacityEffect` обеспечивает эффект непрозрачности.

Класс `QPropertyAnimation` анимирует свойства Qt.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()                               # !!!
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)                    # !!!
        
        self.lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("lena-2.png").scaled(400, 400)      # ваше фото
        self.lbl.setPixmap(self.pix)
        
        self.btn = QPushButton()
        self.btn.setText("Кнопка")
        self.btn.setStyleSheet("""
            background: pink; 
            color: black; 
            border-radius: 34px;
        """)
        self.btn.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Pusia-Bold.otf", 17, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
        self.btn.setFixedSize(300, 150)
        self.btn.setCheckable(True)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.show_image)

        layout = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.lbl, 0, 0, Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn, 1, 0, Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignBottom)
        
        self.eff = QGraphicsOpacityEffect()
        self.eff.setOpacity(0.0)        
        self.lbl.setGraphicsEffect(self.eff)
        
        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self.eff, b'opacity')
        self.animation.setDuration(3000)       
        
    def show_image(self):
        if not self.btn.isChecked():       
            self.animation.setStartValue(1)
            self.animation.setEndValue(0)
        else:    
            self.animation.setStartValue(0)
            self.animation.setEndValue(1)            
        self.animation.start() 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.resize(420, 600)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, это решает мою проблему, но вопрос: как выводить, текст такой же анимацией?

Comment: @TFader так же как и изображение. Анимация выполняется для label.

Comment: А возможно ли выводить изображение и через секунд 5 закрывать её с такой же анимацией без нажатия кнопки?

Comment: @TFader задайте новый вопрос, приложите ваш код и расскажите что вы хотите сделать.